# Base path in php 7

Tags: php, composer-php

I am using

php 7.4.3
composer v4.1.4

I have this error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable() in C:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\app\config\_env.php:9
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\bootstrap\init.php(8): require_once()
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\public\index.php(3): require_once('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\app\config\_env.php on line 9
```

Define base path

_env.php ------------> any other method of defining realpath?

```
<?php

define('BASE_PATH', realpath(__DIR__.'/../../'));

require_once __DIR__.'/../../vendor/autoload.php';

$dotEnv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable(BASE_PATH);

$dotEnv->load();
```

index.php

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/../bootstrap/init.php';

$app_name = getenv('APP_NAME');
echo $app_name;
```

Comment: post your composer.json please

Comment: The `Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable()` function that PHP cannot find belongs to a third-party library. Have you installed it? Also, please double-check you have installed [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) as well because latest stable version as of today is 1.10.5 (v4 is far on the horizon).

Comment: {
    "require": {
        "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^4.1"
    }
}

Comment: My PC run update after two days of battling with the code and it started working. Thanks